# laptop does not support monitor native resolution (2560x1080)

Tags: resolution, amd-radeon, hp-pavilion, amd-catalyst, lg-monitor

I have a LG 29UM65-P monitor with 2560x1080 resolution. I try to show my laptop display on this monitor with HDMI cable, but the max supported resolution in the Windows settings is 1920x1080!

My laptop model is: HP Pavilion DV6 3150 with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 graphic adapter. Is there a way to make it to support 2560x1080 resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HDMI port on your laptop does not support 2560x1080.

HP Pavilion dv6 Entertainment PC, Maintenance and Service Guide (Page 4):

> High-Definition Multimedia Interface (HDMI) v1.3 supporting 1080p and
>   1920 x 1080 at 60 Hz and 1920 x 1200 at 60 Hz DVI Mode

http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02657339

Comment: is there other way to get 2560 x 1080 from this laptop ? i use DVI-D cable with VGA to DVI converter and connect it to my laptop but it`s show no signal on monitor.

Comment: The port cannot display a higher resolution.  An adapter cannot make your video card more capable.